# Import File prevent splitting of sentences

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I have a file that looks like this on Notepad
[image]

When I import it, I get this:

```
Import["file.txt","Table"]
{{7, "Number", "of", "Modes", "X"}, {7, "Number", "of", "Modes", 
  "Y"}, {99.9116, "X-Period,", "nm"}, {100.961, "Y-Period,", 
  "nm"}, {460, "Wavelength,", "nm"}, {0, "Pol", "State,", "deg"}, {0, 
  "Pol", "Phase,", "deg"}, {0, "AngleN,", "deg", "(Cover,", "Plane", 
  "Base)"}, {0, "AngleP,", "deg", "(Cover,", "Plane", "Base)"}, {4, 
  "Number", "of", "Layers"}, {1, 0, "Eps.Re;", "Eps.Im;", 
  "Cover"}, {0, 1, "Layer[1]:", "Thickness,", "nm;", "Number", "of", 
  "Pillars"}, {4, 0, "Base", "Eps.Re;", "Eps.Im"}}
```

As you can see, the sentence "Number of Modes X" was split into its words.
How can I prevent this from happening, to get something like this:

```
{{"7", "Number of Modes X"},
{"7", "Number of Modes Y"},
{"500", "X-Period, nm"},
{"500", "Y-Period,nm"},
{"632.8", "Wavelength, nm"},
{"0", "Pol State, deg"},
{"0", "Pol Phase, deg"},
{"45", "AngleN, deg (Cover, Plane Base)"},
{"0", "AngleP,deg (Cover,Plane Base)"},
{"2", "Number of Layers"},
{"1", "0", "Eps.Re;Eps.Im;Cover"},
{"50", "1" , "Layer[1]:Thickness,nm;Number of Pillars"},
{"1", "0", "Base", "Eps.Re;Eps.Im"}}
```

You can try it out, by downloading the txt file [here](https://pastebin.com/vV6Hx2vL).

Comment: For everybody's convenience, please put the contents of the text file on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) and link to it here.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the link. I did not know Pastebin. That's really convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
StringSplit[#, Repeated[WhitespaceCharacter, {2, ∞}]] & /@ 
Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/vV6Hx2vL", "List"]

   {{"7", "Number of Modes X"}, {"7", "Number of Modes Y"}, 
    {"99.9116197626393", "X-Period, nm"}, {"100.961334707847", "Y-Period, nm"},
    {"460", "Wavelength, nm"}, {"0", "Pol State, deg"},
    {"0", "Pol Phase, deg"}, {"0", "AngleN, deg (Cover, Plane Base)"},
    {"0", "AngleP, deg (Cover, Plane Base)"}, {"4", "Number of Layers"},
    {"1","0", "Eps.Re; Eps.Im; Cover"},
    {"0", "1", "Layer[1]: Thickness, nm; Number of Pillars"},
    {"4", "0", "Base", "Eps.Re; Eps.Im"}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !! :) This is perfect.